# PYTHON DISCORD.PY how to delete messages of a mentioned user

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to create a discord bot (as a troll on a friend), that if send a message in my server:
'!'+(user mention).
from then on, it will delete every message that the **mentioned user** will send. As you can probably see, I am quite a noob and having trouble with the code.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user and message.content == "!"+str({mention}):
 
        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.author.name == {mention} and message.author != client.user:
                await message.delete()
```

I have a few questions...

How can I make it so that the bot deletes the user's messages only if I mentioned the user?

What sort of indication am I supposed to give the bot in order for it to stop deleting the user's messages?

I would greatly appreciate the help! thank you for your time (:

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is pretty simple actually. Since the `discord.Message` object has an attribute called [mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=mentions#discord.Message.mentions), you can take the mentioned users in the form of a list from the message.

Like `mentions = message.mentions`. So you can just run a loop through `mentions` list and check if any of the members in the `mentions` is your friend or target member in other cases, if it is then you can just do your thing.

Also if you need help about clearing the messages of a someone in a channel, you can use `purge()` method with a check in its parameters, more on that [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge).